# How do I configure Docker to use ZFS?

Tags: docker, zfs

I'm trying to get docker to use an existing zpool. According to the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) I should set my storage driver in `/etc/default/docker`:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=zfs"
```

However when I restart the service Docker will not startup:

> level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: prerequisites for driver not satisfied (wrong filesystem?)"

When trying `docker daemon --storage-driver=zfs` I get a similar error.

I am using Docker 1.5-1 in Xenial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should probably also set `zfs.fsName` using `--storage-opt zfs.fsName="filesystem name"`

alternatively you can mount a zfs filesystem to `/var/lib/docker`

Comment: I found that even after mounting my ZFS file system to ```/var/lib/docker``` I still had to manually load the driver using ```--storage-driver=zfs```